# MikroTik bandwidth management

Tags: bandwidth

I have a 16mbps/1mbps speed for Internet access. When a user downloads a file at full speed or torrent, other users can't browse because connections time out.

Is it possible to share bandwidth dynamically, like if both users download then speed to be half for both? I don't care about QoS, etc.; just to avoid timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [PCQ](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Queues_-_PCQ_Examples) to assign traffic limits.

Answer (score 0):

Mikrotik has a feature called Bandwidth control.
On [this](http://www.mikrotik.com/testdocs/ros/3.0/qos/queue.php) page you will find examples you need.

Look for: Equal bandwidth sharing among users

Answer (score 0):

The only real control over traffic that you have is traffic on your network, or the traffic leaving your network. You don't have any real control over how fast an outside server sends traffic to your network. That's why DoS attacks work. By the time the traffic reaches your network the WAN bandwidth is already used.

There are ways to try to mitigate this:

- As JoeriBe pointed out, MikroTik has a was to prevent the incoming
  traffic from being delivered to a user, but that doesn't directly
  prevent the WAN bandwidth from be monopolized by the incoming
  traffic, it just prevents the user from receiving all of it. This may
  or may not have any effect. If the incoming traffic is TCP, it can
  have the effect of changing the TCP window size, and that can slow
  down the server to a degree. If the traffic is UDP, it may not
  have any effect at all, except to create problems for the user.
- You can also come to an agreement with your ISP to limit incoming
  traffic from a single source to a certain percentage of your WAN
  bandwidth. This way, the traffic from a single source cannot
  overwhelm your incoming bandwidth. This is the only sure way, but it
  may cost some money, and you have to decide if it is worth it to your
  business.

Answer (score 0):

```
/ip firewall mangle
add chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=conn-download passthrough=yes protocol=tcp dst-port=80 connection-bytes=1000000-0 comment="CONN-DOWNLOAD"
add chain=prerouting action=mark-packet new-packet-mark=download-packet passthrough=no connection-mark=conn-download
add chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=conn-browsing passthrough=yes protocol=tcp dst-port=80 connection-bytes=0-1000000 comment="CONN-BROWSING"
add chain=prerouting action=mark-packet new-packet-mark=browsing-packet passthrough=no connection-mark=conn-browsing


/queue tree
add name="paket browsing" parent=global-in packet-mark=browsing-packet limit-at=0 queue=default priority=1 max-limit=0 burst-limit=0 burst-threshold=0 burst-time=0s
add name="paket download" parent=global-in packet-mark=download-packet limit-at=0 queue=default priority=8 max-limit=0 burst-limit=0 burst-threshold=0 burst-time=0s
```

Comment: Please consider adding some details on what these commands do.